# Убрать id из адресной строки, Yii2

Tags: yii2, url

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать id из адресной строки? Что бы было не так, `http://poll.ua/gonki/gonki-na-dronah/16`, а вот так `http://poll.ua/gonki/gonki-na-dronah`. В URLmanager в rules, у меня следующее:

```
'<slug>/<slug1>/<poll_id:\d+>' => 'site/competition/',
```

И статьи я выбираю через poll_id:

```
public function actionCompetition($poll_id)
{
     $comp = ACompetition::findOne($poll_id);
     return $this->render('competition', [
                'comp' => $comp,
                ];
}
```

Comment: Надо описать метод, который будет получать данные по ЧПУ вместо findOne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я это реализовывал вот так:

С учётом того что у нас есть таблица с категориями `Category`, у каждой категории есть поле `alias`(в вашем варианте это категория с `alias = 'gonki'`), а в таблице ACompetition у нас только ссылка на категорию по id.

Правило в UrlManager:

```
'<category:[\w\-]+>/<alias:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/competition/'
```

Action:

```
public function actionCompetition($category, $alias)
{
     $category = Category::findOne(['alias' => $category]);
     $comp = ACompetition::findOne(['category_id' => $category->id, 'alias' => $alias]);

     return $this->render('competition', [
         'comp' => $comp,
     ];
}
```